# FsLexYacc : Tests/MiniProject "incorrect Import in .fsproj"

Tags: f#, fsyacc, fslex

On *github*, **FsLexYacc** project has a test dir. I try to set up the simplest one ("LexAndYaccMiniProject").

I follow these steps :

1/ Create an F# console app named *"LexAndYaccMiniProject"*

2/ Install package ("**PM >** Install-Package FsLexYacc" from **VS 2013 Community** which runs successfully but only creates files in packages directory under the project directory)

3/ Close solution

4/ Copy all the files (*Lexer.fsl, Parser.fsy,Program.fs,LexAndYaccMiniProject.fsproj,App.config*) from github to local project directory

5/Open solution
--> Error Message saying there is no such "bin\Debug\FsLexYacc.targets" file.

From FsLexYacc [main page](http://fsprojects.github.io/FsLexYacc/) install instruction, I get a link to a .fsproj that contains :

```
<Import Project="..\packages\FsLexYacc.6.0.4\bin\FsLexYacc.targets" />
```

which relates to another project (*TestProjectUsingNugetPackage*) different from the link found in "**Example**" section just above referring to my already copied project ("*LexAndYaccMiniProject*").

Obviously, the FsLexYacc main page install instruction section refers by link to two distinct projects hosted on github recently.

**Question** : What are the steps I am missing ? What should I check next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could set up the Test projects by using the following (obvious except for a newbie) steps :

1. Download zipped project FsLexYacc from github
2. Build entire solution of FsLexYacc.sln (7 projects)
3. Go to the *tests* subdir and modify the *Mini* project .fsproj so that it looks like the one of *Json* project, specifically :

> ```
> <Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
>   <HintPath>..\fsyacc\Fsharp.Core\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
> </Reference>
> <Reference Include="FsLexYacc.Runtime">
>   <HintPath>..\..\bin\Debug\FsLexYacc.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
> </Reference>
> ```

also remove the reference to .*fsi* file and put the .*fsy*, .*fsl* and .*fs* files in the same order as done in *Json* .fsproj.

4. Build TestProjects solution (2 projects)

Thanks to @kkm000 at github/fsprojects/FsLexYacc.